# Prove that $(A \cup B) \triangle A = A \setminus B$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

> Prove that $(A \cup B) \triangle A = A \setminus B$.

I understand how to prove this by showing it shaded on a Venn diagram. However, I'm a bit unsure in how to prove both the LHS and RHS formally.

Comment: Unwind the def; $A \setminus B=A \cap B^c$

Comment: Are you sure it is not $B\setminus A$?

Comment: As stated, problem is incorrect. [Try it, say, with $A=\{1,2,3\}$, $B=\{2,3,4,5\}$.]

Comment: What happens if $x\in B$ but $x\notin A$?

Comment: @Jan Your are right, and see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since

\begin{align*}
(A\cup B)\triangle A&=((A\cup B)\setminus A)\cup(A\setminus (A\cup B))\\
&=(B\setminus A)\cup\varnothing\\
&=B\setminus A,
\end{align*}

then the equality should be $(A\cup B)\triangle A=\color{red}{B\setminus A}$, or $(A\cup B)\triangle \color{red}{B}=A\setminus B$. And we also prove the equality.